# SPFX - What is the scss variable for the themes primary colour?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, theme

What is the scss variable for the themes primary color (orange)?

I am using: `$ms-color-themePrimary`

But this is giving me a blue color and not the orange one displayed in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to follow below Microsoft documentation to use theme colors in your SharePoint Framework customizations:

[Use theme colors in your SharePoint Framework customizations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations)

You can also check all the available theme color values on your SharePoint site by typing `__themeState__` into the console.

The variables for use in the styles come from Microsoft's [Fluent UI Theme Slots](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/styles/web/colors/theme-slots).

As per my knowledge the HEX for orange color used in SharePoint is `#CA5010`.

**Additional Reference**: [How to use Theme Colors in SPFX Web Parts](https://n8d.at/how-to-use-theme-colors-in-spfx-web-parts/)

Comment: Seems like you are using correct variable but it is applying default blue color.

Comment: However in scss, you can also define your own variable like `$ms-themePrimary:         "[theme:themePrimary, default: #0078d7]";` and use them in your solution. check the last link provided in my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks mate all working now :)

Answer (score 0):

"[theme: themePrimary, default: #000000]";

That is how to use the default theme primary color.